# why pods created by the Deployment running on NotReady node all the time

Tags: kubernetes

I have three nodes. when I shutdown  `cdh-k8s-3.novalocal` ,pods running on it all the time

```
# kubectl get node
NAME                  STATUS     ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
cdh-k8s-1.novalocal   Ready      control-plane,master   15d   v1.20.0
cdh-k8s-2.novalocal   Ready      <none>                 9d    v1.20.0
cdh-k8s-3.novalocal   NotReady   <none>                 9d    v1.20.0
```

```
# kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE                  NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-5jtqv   1/1     Running   0          3h28m   10.244.26.110   cdh-k8s-3.novalocal   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-fntn4   1/1     Running   0          3h28m   10.244.26.108   cdh-k8s-3.novalocal   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5-vz7hr   1/1     Running   0          3h28m   10.244.26.109   cdh-k8s-3.novalocal   <none>           <none>
```

my yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```
# kubectl get deployment
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   0/3     3            0           3h28m
```

I find the [Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#taint-nodes-by-condition)

```
DaemonSet pods are created with NoExecute tolerations for the following taints with no tolerationSeconds:

node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
This ensures that DaemonSet pods are never evicted due to these problems.
```

But it is DaemonSet and not Deployment

Comment: please make sure that there are no `Taints` on the other nodes.

Comment: no `taints` ,it can create on cdh-k8s-2.novalocal

Comment: Are you running `kubectl get pod -o wide` and `kubectl get deployment` at the same time ? Those two results look contradictory. 1st shows that you have 3 `Ready` pods which are `Running` and 2nd suggests that this `Deployment` has `0/3` `Ready` pods. If they are not properly scheduled on some available node, first command shouldn't show you those pods as `Running`.

Comment: Wht is your Kubernetes version? Pods sould go in Terminating status and probably remain in that status until the shutten down node comes back up.. but the scheduler should schedule new Pods on other nodes. As a workaround, you could also use nodeAntiAffinity to schedule each Pod of the deployment on a different node

Comment: yes, at the same time .vinison all 1.20.I submitted an issue on GitHub(https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/98511). Maybe he doesn't think it's a bug

Comment: When you say "shutdown node" how exactly are you doing this? What does `kubectl describe node cdh-k8s-3.novalocal` tell you in this shutdown state?